# getting music player control in lock screen like Pandora app in iphone

Tags: iphone

iphone Pandora app(in ios-4) supports controlling the audio from the lock screen like play,pause,next and prev.

How to get the music player control action from the lock screen.

can any one give me an idea about getting the actions of these control to native application from lock screen like pandora app.

Answer (score 2):

this miight help

[using-lock-screen-for-my-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134785/using-lock-screen-for-my-app)